# On the proof of the uniqueness of smooth structures on submanifolds by John Lee

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am having difficulty with an argument in the proof below. So we assume $\tilde{S}$ to be an immersed submanifold with some topology other than the subspace topology and some smooth structure, and $S$ be the same set with the subspace topology and the smooth structure constructed from k-slice charts. Since $\tilde{S}$ is an immersed submanifold, the inclusion map $\tilde{i}: \tilde{S}\to M$ is an injective immersion and $\tilde{i}(\tilde{S})=S$. Because $S$ is embedded, Corollary 5.30 implies that $\tilde{i}$ as a map from $\tilde{S}$ to $S$ is also smooth.

But then I don't follow the composition below. How do we have $\tilde{i}=\tilde{i} \circ i$, where $i:S \to M$ is the inclusion map from the embedded manifold $S$ to $M$?
Topologically this makes sense but in terms of manifolds, I can't quite grasp why we get the equality here because the right map is from the immersed submanifold to the ambient manifold $M$, and the left is a composition of a map from the immersed submanifold to the embedded submanifold and to the ambient manifold.

Or in a more general case (Theorem 5.33) where $S$ is a weakly embedded submanifold ($S$ may not have subspace topology), and $S'$ is another set with some topology and smooth structure with respect to which it is an immersed submanifold.
Again, the proof uses the fact that $i':S' \to S$ is smooth since $S$ is weakly embedded, and follow the lines below that $i':S' \to M$ is a composition of $i':S' \to S$ and $i:S\to M$. How can we conclude that they are equal maps in terms of continuous and smooth maps?

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could clarify this to me.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting confused by a common abuse of notation. Call $\tilde i:\tilde S\to M$ and $i:S\to M$ to the inclusions. And write $\tilde i':\tilde S\to S$ for the co-restriction, so $i\circ\tilde i'=\tilde i$. Since $i$ is an embedding, the co-restriction $\tilde i'$ is also smooth (see e.g. Corollary 5.30). Since $\tilde i$ is an immersion $d\tilde i_p=di_p\circ d\tilde i'_p$ is injective, then $d\tilde i'_p$ must be injective. The proof follows by noting that $\tilde i':\tilde S\to S$ is an immersion and a bijection, hence a diffeomorphism (Lee's Global Rank Thm).

Comment: Well that is exactly what the proof states. My question is why is the composition equal to the inclusion because two inclusions from the same set to the same set may differ under different topology and smooth structure which is what we assume here. So one inclusion is straight from $\tilde{S}$ to $M$ and another is from $\tilde{S}$ to $S$ to $M$ and the first inclusion can be different from the inclusion $S$ to $M$

Comment: $\tilde S$, $S$ and $M$ are not just sets but manifolds, each of them with its own smooth structure. And $\tilde i:\tilde S\to M$, $i:S\to M$ and $\tilde i':\tilde S\to S$ are not just functions but smooth maps. The first two are smooth by hypothesis, and the third one is smooth because embedded submanifolds are initial (or, if you prefer, Corollary 5.30).  The composition $i \circ \tilde i'$ is equal to $\tilde i$ because they agree as functions, set-theoretically. Hope that helps.